# Align Hyperlink in HTML

Tags: html

I have a table, with its last row containing a hyperlink.

This hyperlink has been placed inside the tabledata tag of tablerow

My code looks like this :

```
<tr align="center">
           <td><a th:href="@{/person/new}">Add Person</a></td>
            </tr>
```

Now, I want to align this hyperlink to the center in the row.

How do I do this?

**I have used thymeleaf**

Comment: Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: I tried <td align="center"> It increases the width of the row

Comment: I want the hyperlink to appear in the center of the row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you have to make the `<td>` the width of `<tr>` container via the [rowspan attr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-rowspan) then you should displace the `align=center` attr from the `<tr>` tag to the `<td>` tag. And *voilà* !

Comment: something like this? <tr rowspan="2"><td align="center"></td></tr>

Comment: I also tried this :  <tr>
   <td rowspan="2"><a th:href="@{/person/new}">Add Person</a></td>
   </tr>    It doesn't work

Comment: I even tried colspan<tr>
   <td colspan="4"><a th:href="@{/person/new}">Add Person</a></td>
   </tr>  enlarges the row width. It does not place the hyperlink text at the center